# Why is htmlspecialchars not converting quotes?

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

I am trying to convert a single quote into html specialchars.. but its not working.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Below is how I am using the function

```
echo htmlspecialchars("Housemade Mac N' Cheese",ENT_QUOTES);
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Do a _View Source_ on the web page, the browser renders the entity as `'`.

Comment: What is extension of your file .php or .html ?

Comment: Do single quotes need conversion?

Comment: I tested it, seems fine. https://ideone.com/NB95rl

Answer (score 0):

The following comes from my own experiment.

Try this, it will replace all single quote by **ߴ**, which is an Unicode character. `nko high tone apostrophe (U+07F4)`. Php/js will treat it as a regular character, so no headaches here.

Of course the content of `$string` is going to be altered, this is not the perfect solution but a workaround.

```
echo htmlspecialchars(preg_replace("/'/","ߴ",$string),ENT_QUOTES);
```

To understand it better, in your showcase, the following should be ok, but what if the string will change to something you don't know yet. Will it contains single quotes, on, two, three, where? This is hard stuff! Look simple but it is actually a very complex case!

```
echo htmlspecialchars("Housemade Mac N\' Cheese",ENT_QUOTES);
```

Philosophical annexe, this part can be skipped...

> The most complex things are hiding in the simplest.

Personal reflexion